# How i can override user save Django allauth.socialaccounts

Tags: django, django-allauth

I need to override user save method in my custom OAuth2Adapter. How i can do this?
I need save some special fields in my user Model

**auth_provider/views.py**

```
import requests
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.views import (
    OAuth2Adapter,
    OAuth2CallbackView,
    OAuth2LoginView,
)

from config.settings.base import EXAMPLE_URLS
from app.users.auth_provider.provider import ExampleProvider


class ExampleAdapter(OAuth2Adapter):
    provider_id = ExampleProvider.id
    access_token_url = EXAMPLE_URLS["web"] + "oauth/token"
    authorize_url = EXAMPLE_URLS["web"] + "oauth/authorize"
    profile_url = EXAMPLE_URLS["api"] + "me"

    def complete_login(self, request, app, access_token, **kwargs):
        headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer %s" % access_token}
        extra_data = requests.get(self.profile_url, headers=headers)

        return self.get_provider().sociallogin_from_response(request, extra_data.json())


oauth2_login = OAuth2LoginView.adapter_view(ExampleAdapter)
oauth2_callback = OAuth2CallbackView.adapter_view(ExampleAdapter)
```